# Cannot push from Source Tree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, gitolite

I am using source tree and every time I try and do a push it gives me the following error:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags --  set-upstream origin master:master
Pushing to ssh://git@sandbox.dev:2222/dashboard.git

Access denied
Access denied
Access denied
FATAL ERROR: Server sent disconnect message
type 2 (protocol error):

"Too many authentication failures"




fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.





Completed with errors, see above.
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this and how it is being caused?

Comment: Is `--  set-upstream `  a typo? It should be `--set-upstream `

Comment: Also check http://superuser.com/q/187779/141